# Any idea how to send operation name in SOAP action

Tags: xml, soap, soapui

need help on a POC we are working on .. we need to send operation name in SOAP action using SOAPUI or some other tool.

We can send from SAOPUI if we have WS-Addresing selected, but this will inserts an action tag.

Comment: Are you saying that the WSDL you're using says not to send the operation name, but you want to send it anyway? Where do you want to send it? What do you expect the server to do with it?

Comment: @JohnSaunders - thanks for your response. Issue is when I dont have WSAddressing enabled, I dont see Action in request message going to target server and same apply in response message.. but when we have WSAddressing enabled, in soap-env:Header, Operation name is coming in Action tag...

Comment: Is there any way we should not enable WSAddressing, and can get action in payload.

Comment: But SoapUI sets things up according to the WSDL. It should be sending what the WSDL requires to be sent. Does that not work properly? Why do you feel you need to send the operation name?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [custom header](http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/adding-headers-and-attachments.html#1-custom-http-headers) in each request, call it something like `x-action`, and send the operation name there.